# what *.ko do i need to move after cross-build linux kernel and modules

Tags: linux-device-driver, raspberry-pi, embedded-linux

I cross-compile linux kernel and modules on VMbox for raspberrt-pi, 
and it can boot from new "zimage" file.

but "lsmod", it return nothing.

```
    $ lsmod
    Module                  Size  Used by
```

if i move some *.ko file like spi_bcm2835.ko to pi and .

```
    $ sudo insmod spi_bcm2835.ko
    $ lsmod
    Module                  Size  Used by
    spi_bcm2835             2673  0
```

It seems that *.ko in pi is not match the kernel version.
Is there any rule to know that what *.ko files should 
be moved to pi, and what path they should be?

thanks

Comment: You know that there is a raspberry pi stack exchange site?? http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @mathematician1975 thanks! that's helpful!